# Errors when migrating from codeigniter 1.7 to 2.1

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I am developing a few pages in codeigniter 1.7 and when I change to version 2.1 my code will show me this error message:

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/translate_helper.php

Comment: how are you loading helper, can you show the code...?

Answer (score 0):

You can read about all changes in changelog.

[Upgrading from 1.7.2 to 2.0.0](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to follow the migration step from 1.7.2 to 2.0 via this post: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html

And please have a look to common issue and help in the forum that might help you:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/209890/